# EF Core and Automapper. Mapping relationship one-to-many

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core-3.1

I'm currently using AutoMapper on an Project running code-first Entity Framework.

Here just simple entities and DTO's:

```csharp
// DTO Profile
public class CreateOrEditProfileDto 
{        
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<RouteDto> Routes { get; set; }
}

// entity Profile
public class Profile
{       
    public virtual string Code { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}

// DTO Route
public class RouteDto 
{
    public string DriverName { get; set; }
    public string DriverSurname { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int ProfileId { get; set; }
}

//entity Route
public class Route
{
    public virtual string DriverName { get; set; }
    public virtual string DriverSurname { get; set; }
    public virtual string Phone { get; set; }
    public virtual string Email { get; set; }
    public virtual int ProfileId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ProfileId")]
    public Profile ProfileFk { get; set; }
}

//Mapper
configuration.CreateMap<RouteDto, Route>().ReverseMap();
// configuration.CreateMap<CreateOrEditProfileDto, Profile>().ReverseMap();

// this type of configuration give the error written below
configuration.CreateMap<CreateOrEditProfileDto, Profile>()
     .ForMember(dest => dest, opt =>
        opt.MapFrom(src => src.Routes.Select(x =>
           new Route()
              {
                  ProfileId = x.ProfileId,
                  DriverName = x.DriverName,
                  DriverSurname = x.DriverSurname,
                  Phone = x.Phone,
                  Email = x.Email,
              }
           )
        )
     );
```

I'm a little bit confusing, I'm trying to map one-to-many relationship between Profile and Route, Route has a foreign key to Profile. A single profile could have more routes. So, I want to create a profile and attach the list of routes, but when I compile the solution, I get this error:

> AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException: 'Custom configuration for members is only supported for top-level individual members on a type.'

Does anyone know the best way to solve this mapping?

Regards

Comment: If this help you, could you please click 'accept this answer'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `List<RouteDto>` is mapped to `Profile`, the type does not match. You need to add a property in `Profile`.

```
 public class Profile
{
    public virtual string Code { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Route> Routes { get; set; }
}
```

The mapping attribute `dest.Routes` need to be specified. Then, the `Routes` will be automatically mapped.

```
  CreateMap<CreateOrEditProfileDto, EntityProfile>()
          .ForMember(dest => dest.Routes, opt =>
             opt.MapFrom(src => src.Routes.Select(x=>
             new Route()
             {
                 ProfileId = x.ProfileId,
                 DriverName = x.DriverName,
                 DriverSurname = x.DriverSurname,
                 Phone = x.Phone,
                 Email = x.Email,
             }
             ))
          );
```

Comment: Great, it works! Is it necessary to do a new migration to save the new navigation property on the modelsnapshot? Ty in advance

Comment: If you want to change the profile structure saved in the database, it is necessary to re-migrate.